# python update outer passed value from within a for loop

Tags: python, reference, for-loop, immutability

My question is a slight variation of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) - however I still can't find a *simple* solution to the problem illustrated below: how can I alter the values of the outer string variables from within a for-loop?

```
str1 = 'before'
str2 = 'before'

for i in str1,str2:
    print "%s" % (i)
    i = "after"

for i in str1,str2:
    print "%s" % (i)
```

Thanks for the helpful responses below however they haven't really helped with my specific problem, the code below is less generic but better reflects my use case:

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.feedburner.com/FrontlineAudiocastPbs?format=xml')
name = d.feed.title[:127]
description = d.feed.subtitle[:255]

strs = [name,description]
for i, s in enumerate(strs):
    try:
      strs[i] = unicode(strs[i])
    except:
      strs[i] = "Invalid unicode detected!"

for s in name,description:
  print s
```

You can see that the two original string variables are not being updated. The for-loop is intended to detect and handle malformed string such as the assignment to 'description'.. so any 'associated' advice would be appreciated.

I like the *elegance* of the list comprehension slice assignment approach below and would ideally use that technique.

Comment: You can't. `i` is iterating over the string values, which are immutable, not the variables.

Comment: Perhaps you want a list of strings instead of a series of variables? If you tell us more about your actual program and the data it needs, we can help you find a good solution.

Comment: Could you provide a use case for what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is to structure your data differently, for example by using:

```
d = {'str1': 'before', 'str2': 'before'}
for i in d:
    print d[i]
    d[i] = "after"
```

*The important thing is that this variable is mutable (as discussed in your link).*

Answer (score 5):

Make a list of strings instead of dealing with them as separate variables, then you can loop over them with `enumerate`:

```
strs = ['before', 'before']
for i, s in enumerate(strs):
    print s
    strs[i] = "after"

print strs
```

Comment: +1 Without knowing the actual use case of the OP, this is the way I'd go

Comment: Cool! enumerate(strs) is an important part here

Answer (score 1):

```
strs = ['before', 'before']
strs[:] = ['after' for s in strs]
```

Comment: That adds an unnecessary layer of confusion I find. This way you're not only changing the list, you're replacing it with a completely new list.

Comment: @Lukas: Incorrect. Slice assignment preserves the original list, keeping its references intact.

Comment: Oh, right, my mistake. I somehow read it as `strs = ['after' for s in strs[:]]` (Using slicing to create a copy of the list, not slice assignment)

Answer (score -1):

```
str1 = 'before'
str2 = 'before'

import sys
currentobject = sys.modules[__name__]

for i in 'str1', 'str2':
    setattr(currentobject, i, 'after')

for i in str1,str2:
    print "%s" % (i)
```

Comment: You wouldn't do this in your own programs, why recommend it for someone else?

Comment: In certain situations I would/have, though I agree it is unneccesary in the use-case that has now been added.